# how to parse both data & binary websocket messages?

Tags: javascript, parsing, binary, websocket, message

I've found [this great page](http://badankles.com/?p=209) that shows how to stream video.

His code assumes that the `onmessage` data is `jpg` like so

```
ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    $("#image").attr('src',  'data:image/jpg;base64,'+e.data);
}
```

but I'd like to have audio and other page data as well.

How can WebSockets be made to parse message types and binary types?

Comment: include message types in data and build your own protocol

Comment: @fmgp right, but if the binary's in `base64` and the `onmessage` `e.type` is `String`, how can it be done?  (I purposefully left out what I've investigated to prevent corrupting the answers)

Comment: base64 is string representation of binary, so you can wrap other metadata

Comment: @fmgp and it all comes together now...  thanks!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data in Websocket messages can be either string (text messages) or binary data. In your case it's string data, where the string content is the base64 encoding of a binary image.
In a better optimized program the image could be also transferred binary.

Depending on the message type, e.data will be of another type.

1. If the message is a text message then e.data will be of type string.
2. If the message is a binary message then e.data will contain either an `ArrayBuffer` or a `Blob` object. You can by yourself decide which representation of binary data you want to receive by setting the `WebSocket.binaryType` property (e.g. to `"arraybuffer"`).

You can use `instanceof` to check if you received a binary or text message.

If you want to transfer different types of binary data you can use a header at the start of the message to tell the client what the message contains. E.g. declare the first byte of the binary data as header. If the first byte contains 1 then the remaining data is a picture, if the first byte contains 2 then the remaining data is a short audio sample, etc.
However it's a little more difficult on both sides since you need to split or combine the binary data array.

Alternatively you could use multiple parallel websocket connections between client and server. On for video data, one for audio data, one for general messages, etc.

Comment: yes, i'd like to transfer binary since i've heard it's 33% smaller, but would you mind writing out some example code for storing the image and some sort of identifier in the same `send` data?  that's the part i'm most confused about.  i don't want to send a message that notifies the server that binary's coming.  i'd like the message information (if it's audio or video, time, etc) and the binary in one.  thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Updated the answer to give you some hints about how that's usually done.

Comment: Good explanation, Thanks!